Can’t boot into LFS using GRUB
I have made LFS. 
But unfortunately, when I installed GRUB,
I got an error that said ext2 system isn’t supported. 
But I added --force into grub-install --force /dev/sda and it installed,
so I tried rebooting, and it automatically puts me into GRUB rescue shell. 
Is there any way to repair it, or do I have to compile everything again?
I tried finding a kernel from the GRUB shell to load it,
but I can’t really find anything. 
And, when doing ls (hd0,gpt1), I don’t see any files or directories.

My first guess is that you didn't create a "BIOS boot partition" or have it formatted (I mean you shouldn't). You pretty much never want to grub-install with --force. If it can't complete without it, it's almost for sure you have done something wrong.

And why EXT2? It's a filesystem from the past century, literally.

@TomYan thanks for answer, is it still possible for me to fix it by deleting and creating bios boot partition once again and installing grub after that?

@ChanganAuto as from what i know it is pretty simple file system and i heard from someone its better to use simple file systems for boot partitions (i might be wrong im not really any expert more like hobbyst or student)

Linux supports a wide variety of filesystems but EXT2 is hopelessly out of date and has been superseded by EXT3 and EXT4, the latter the most used nowadays. And modern GRUB doesn't support it as you found out already. And what do you mean by boot partition exactly? A separated /boot is seldom needed (some server implementations use it). Do not confuse it with the ESP (EFI System Partition) that's required for any UEFI based computer, i.e., anything from 2012 or newer. That one must be FAT32 as per UEFI standards.

The unformatted "BIOS boot partition" (~1-1MB) mentioned in the 1st comment is only necessary when forcing a "BIOS"/Legacy/CSM installation onto a GPT drive (in lieu of the MBR that the old 'msdos' partitioning type has). I'm not sure if doing that is advisable and, likewise, choosing EXT2 is shooting your own feet.

@ChanganAuto thanks for explaining it helped me a lot. I decided to switch from GPT to MBR but i have my entire LFS on disk with GPT and if i copy it to other disk i create with MBR ( first format it) and do i need the separate /boot partition of size 250MB? I use BIOS boot on vmware 17.5 pro

i have been always told and always made /boot partition and it worked well and i always used the BIOS

What you've been told is also outdated an lacks nuance. There's a reason why not a single mainstream distro installer creates a separated boot partition when allowed to automatically partition, enough said. And you're again confusing a lot of things here -and- 250MB is ridiculously small nowadays, another reason why /bootis left as just a folder inside the root. I seems that the people you've been listening to are very old and outdated themselves.

@ChanganAuto alrigh now i understand lol. Thanks a lot for help. Do you maybe know any good tool to just copy my root partition to other disk so i can make it work, also will the symlinks and stuff stay there?

Sorry, can't help with that. I can't even imagine what's going on there. In any case I wouldn't bother copying something with EXT2.

@ChanganAuto well i mean i want just copy the sda3 (root) partition

its in ext4 file system

Read the note at the top of the LFS page 10.4. Using GRUB to Set Up the Boot Process: "If your system has UEFI support and you wish to boot LFS with UEFI, you should skip the instructions in this page but still learn the syntax of grub.cfg and the method to specify a partition in the file from this page, and configure GRUB with UEFI support using the instructions provided in the BLFS page." Most modern systems use UEFI/GPT, with ESP.

BLFS page Using GRUB to Set Up the Boot Process with UEFI has information on how to setup GRUB with UEFI/GPT. For perhaps a better overview of partitioning, there is an Arch wiki article on Partitioning.

Does this answer your question? Overwritten MBR: Is partial/complete recovery possible?
